# Recursive copy set folder to ignore

Tags: php, recursion, directory, copy

I'm using this function to copy parts of WordPress into a backup directory, however when I backup the plugins directory the program enters an infinite loop, is there a way to set a folder to ignore while copying the folders? from echoing out $dir I just get #resource ID x

```
function sisb_content_dir_copy($src, $dst) {
$dir = opendir($src);
// Make the destination directory if not exist
@mkdir($dst);

// Loop through the files in source directory
while( $file = readdir($dir) ) {
  echo $file."</br>";
    if (( $file != '.' ) && ( $file != '..' )){
        if ( is_dir($src . '/' . $file) )
        {

            // Recursively calling custom copy function
            // for sub directory
            sisb_content_dir_copy($src . '/' . $file, $dst . '/' . $file);

        }
        else {
            copy($src . '/' . $file, $dst . '/' . $file);
        }
    }
}

closedir($dir);
```

}

Comment: So this isn't hidden, this is your loop.  So once you know it is a directory, if it is called "plugins" (or whatever) skip processing for that directory.  Or have I missed what your question is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as you 're running a PHP version greater than 5.4 you can use the PHP built-in DirectoryIterator and FilterIterator classes to achieve your goal. With the Filter class you can declare which files and directories are accepted by the iterator. Beside that the built-in iterator classes are faster and don 't mess around with memory consumption. Here 's a little example.

```
<?php
$directory = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path, FilesystemIterator::FOLLOW_SYMLINKS);
$filter = new RecursiveCallbackFilterIterator($directory, function($current, $key, $iterator) {
    // Skip hidden files and directories.
    if ($current->getFilename()[0] === '.') {
        return FALSE;
    }

    if ($current->isDir()) {
        // Only recurse into intended subdirectories
        return $current->getFilename() === 'wanted_dirname';
    } else {
       // Only consume files of interest.
       return strpos($current->getFilename(), 'wanted_filename') === 0;
    }
});

$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($filter);
$files = [];

foreach ($iterator as $info) {
   $files[] = $info->getPathname();
}
```

The `$files` array contains all the files which pass the callback filter. These files you can copy whereever you want. The [RecursiveCallbackFilterIterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivecallbackfilteriterator) class is a PHP built-in class, you can use since PHP 5.4 onwards.

This example is taken from the PHP documentation for the [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php#114504) class. Thanks to sun, who did this six years ago.

Hope that helps. ;)

Comment: Good solution, ended up using another way for easier compatibility but im accepting this answer as it is the best solution

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is better as long as you have access to a high enough PHP version, this works for other versions though

```
function sisb_content_dir_copy($src, $dst) {
//echo $src.'</br>';
$dir = opendir($src);
//echo '</br>'.$dst;
// Make the destination directory if not exist
//if (!file_exists('/srv/www/sisb/public_html/wp-content/plugins/WP-SISB/contentbackups')) {
@mkdir($dst);
//}
// Loop through the files in source directory
while( $file = readdir($dir) ) {
  echo $file."</br>";
    if (( $file != '.' ) && ( $file != '..' )){
        if ( is_dir($src . '/' . $file) && ($file !='unwanted folder'))
        {

            // Recursively calling custom copy function
            // for sub directory
            sisb_content_dir_copy($src . '/' . $file, $dst . '/' . $file);

        }
        else {
          if($file !='unwanted folder'){
            copy($src . '/' . $file, $dst . '/' . $file);
          }
        }
    }
}

closedir($dir);
```

}